# How to avoid action from within store update

Tags: redux

As far as my understanding goes, it's an anti-pattern to dispatch actions from within a store update handler. Correct?

How can I handle the following workflow then?

- I have some company switcher on my page header
- Clicking on a company dispatches some `SELECTEDCOMPANY_UPDATE` action
- The active view reacts on the according change in the state store by forcing a data reload. E.g. by calling `companyDataService.fetchOrders(companyName)`.
- I'd like to show some loading animation during the data is being fetched and therefore have an dedicated action like `FETCHINGDATA_UPDATE` which updates the `fetchingData` section in my app state store to which all interested views can react by showing/hiding the load mask

Where do I actually dispatch the `FETCHINGDATA_UPDATE` action? If I directly do this from within `companyDataService.fetchOrders(companyName)` it would be called from within a store update handler (see `OrdersView.onStoreUpdate` in exemplary code below)...

---

## Edit

To clarify my last sentence I'm adding some exemplary code which shows how my implementation would have looked like:

**ActionCreator.js**

```
// ...
export function setSelectedCompany(company) {
  return { type: SELECTEDCOMPANY_UPDATE, company: company };
}

export function setFetchingData(isFetching) {
  return { type: FETCHINGDATA_UPDATE, isFetching: isFetching };
}
// ...
```

**CompanyDataService.js**

```
// ...
export fetchOrders(companyName) {
  this.stateStore.dispatch(actionCreator.setFetchingData(true));
  fetchData(companyName)
    .then((data) => {
      this.stateStore.dispatch(actionCreator.setFetchingData(false));
      // Apply the data...
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.stateStore.dispatch(actionCreator.setFetchingData(false));
      this.stateStore.dispatch(actionCreator.setFetchError(err));
    })
}
// ...
```

**CompanySwitcher.js**

```
// ...
onCompanyClicked(company) {
  this.stateStore.dispatch(actionCreator.setSelectedCompany(company));
}
// ...
```

**OrdersView.js**

```
// ...
constructor() {
  this._curCompany = '';
  this.stateStore.subscribe(this.onStoreUpdate);
}
// ...
onStoreUpdate() {
  const stateCompany = this.stateStore.getState().company;
  if (this._curCompany !== stateCompany) {
    // We're inside a store update handler and `fetchOrders` dispatches another state change which is considered bad...
    companyDataService.fetchOrders(stateCompany);
    this._curCompany = stateComapny;
  }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Inside your action creator is the best place.  I'm a bit confused with the last sentence - `it would be called from within a store update handler`.  Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Davin,  in the action creator is the place to do this, something like:

```
export function fetchOrders (company) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch ({ type: FETCHINGDATA_UPDATE });
    return fetchOrderFunction ().then(
      (result) => dispatch ({ type: FETCHING_COMPLETED, result }),
      (error) => dispatch ({ type: FETCHING_FAILED, error })
    );
  };
}
```

Then in the reducer FETCHINGDATA_UPDATE can set your loading indicator to true and you can set it back to false I both SUCCESS and FAILED

Comment: Should action creators actually perform business logic?

Comment: It is a point of user preference, but in short yes, there is no issue with it. In fact Redux suggest that code with side effects should go into the action  creator process. See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic for a more detailed answer